# Умножение с input налету

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как с помощью js (jquery) можно умножать кол-во на сумму налету, и желательно не изменяя структуру HTML:

```html
<span class="price-amount">700<span class="price-symbol">₽</span></span>
<input class="quantity" type="number" value="1" title="Кол-во" inputmode="numeric">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так?

```js
let qty = document.querySelector('.quantity');
let amount = document.querySelector('.price-amount').firstChild;
let price = +amount.textContent;
qty.addEventListener('input', () => amount.textContent = qty.value*price);
```

```html
<span class="price-amount">700<span class="price-symbol">₽</span></span>
<input class="quantity" type="number" value="1" title="Кол-во" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!